# Autocomplete ="off" , Autocomplete ="Nope" , Autocomplete ="false" Not Working on chrome

Tags: angularjs, input, autocomplete

I'm using angularjs + HTML5 , and i need to be able to disable all my input fields autocomplete , i have tried adding autocomplete=false,nope,off, random number , field name
And none worked!
I have tried adding angularjs directive buts still having the same result
I did a temporary workaround adding an empty hidden input field , that did work , but i have a big project with a huge amount of inputs so i cannot do this on every single field
Any help?

Comment: MDN's [autocomplete documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) may help. "In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a site's login form."

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer, but I recommend you, to go and tell the Chromium developers that you have a use case, where unwanted autocomplete="off" should not be obeyed.

See their questionnaire at:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466